# How to search by both first name and last name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, search, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am doing a search screen (to search list of names) on my iPhone app, where I need to search by both first name and last name.

Say my search tableview contains names like follows

```
Ravi Kiran 
sujay huilgol
harry potter
```

My search is working for only first name i.e if I search for **Ra** it will show **Ravi Kiran** but when I search for **Kiran** it's not displaying **Ravi Kiran**.

My **`filterContentForSearchText`** is like this:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.arrSearhResults removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.
    
    // Search the main list for Usernames whose type matches searchText; add items that match to the filtered array.
    
    for(NSString * strUserName in arrUserInfo )
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [strUserName compare:searchText options:(NSLiteralSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
            [self.arrSearhResults addObject:strUserName];
            //NSLog(@"arrSearhResults %@",arrSearhResults);
        }
    }
    
}
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: NSOrderedSame if the substring of the receiver and aString are equivalent in lexical value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **rangeOfString** to search whole string

```
 for(NSString * strUserName in arrUserInfo )
{
  NSRange range = [strUserName rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
  if (range.length > 0)
  {
    [self.arrSearhResults addObject:strUserName];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(NSString * strUserName in arrUserInfo )
{
  NSRange titleResultsRange = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strUserName] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (titleResultsRange.length){
        [self.arrSearhResults addObject:[self.contacts objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ravi Kiran", @"sujay huilgol", nil];
for (NSString* name in array)
{
    if ([name rangeOfString:@"Kiran"].location != NSNotFound)
        NSLog(@"%@", name);
}
```