# Why can't I search both first and last names using searchBar?

Tags: swift, uitableview, filter, uisearchbar

I have implemented code for `searchBar` and it works if I either search the first or the last name of a person. For example, if I want to search Kate Bell, the search works if I write "Kate", and it works if I write "Bell". But if I write "Kate B" the search result disappear.

Here's my code:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.count == 0 {
        isFiltered = false
        tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
    }else {
        isFiltered = true

        searchInternalArray = contactsInternalArray.filter({ object -> Bool in
            guard let text = searchBar.text else {return false}
            return object.firstName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)) || object.lastName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
        })

        searchArrayGroups = sectionsArrayGroups.filter({ object -> Bool in
            guard let text = searchBar.text else {return false}
            return object.firstName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)) || object.lastName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
        })

        searchArraySAEs = sectionsArraySAEs.filter ({ object -> Bool in
            guard let text = searchBar.text else {return false}
            return object.firstName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)) || object.lastName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
        })


    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I fond this on `SO` [How to search by both first name and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634493/how-to-search-by-both-first-name-and-last-name)

It's in `objective-c` and I have trouble implementing it into my own code. I tried something like this:

```
searchInternalArray = contactsInternalArray.filter({ object -> Bool in
    guard let text = searchBar.text?.range(of: object.firstName + object.lastName) else {return false}
    return object.firstName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)) || object.lastName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
})
```

That's obviously not how it should be implemented though.

***Edit***
Didn't think it was relevant, but perhaps it is: I'm filtering multiple `arrays` since I have data coming from three different sources to the `tableView`. The whole `searchBar` code looks like above. It's updated.

Comment: What's the type of `contactsInternalArray`?

Comment: The linked answer doesn't find "Kate Bell" if you type "Kate B". And what if you search for "B Kate"? Should it find "Kate Bell"?

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor `var contactsInternalArray: [InternalContact]`. And that class gives access to `NSString firstName` and `NSString lastName` among others.

Comment: @Larme Ah, my bad. But yes, searching B Kate should also give result Kate Bell. That would be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, there's a far simpler solution to this:

```
let name = firstname.lowercased() + " " + lastname.lowercased()
return name.contains(text.lowercased())
```

This works for any part of forename, surname, or the a part of the two with a space between.  You should probably still trim leading/trailing spaces, and if you wanted to get rid of issues with variable spaces between the first and last names you could search/replace them double spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create the full name from the two parts and search based on that.

```
let searchResults = contactsInternalArray.filter { object in
    "\(object.firstName) \(object.lastName)".contains(searchText)
}
```

You can still lowercase them and trim if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I got idea from [flanker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628775/11077258)'s answer.
This works for me

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
         
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        
        if searchText != ""{
            self.isSearchActive = true
            
            if self.object.count != 0{
                
                
                filteredContacts = self. object.filter(){
                //("\(($0 as FetchedContact).firstName.lowercased()) \(($0 as FetchedContact).object.lowercased()) \(($0 as FetchedContact).telephone.lowercased())")
                let name = ("\(($0 as ContactModel).firstName.lowercased()) \(($0 as ContactModel).lastName.lowercased()) \(($0 as ContactModel).mobileNumber.lowercased())")
                    return name.contains(searchText.lowercased())
                }
                
                
            }
            self.tblContactList.reloadData()
        }
        
     }
```

- Which search on the base of FirsName, LastName and MobileNumber for Contacts.